# Alsa asynchronous callback

Tags: linux, asynchronous, resume, alsa

I am trying to use the asynchronous callback functionality of ALSA so that I can provide the pause and resume functionality at the application level. But the function `async_add_pcm_handler()` returns an error (returns -38 to be more specific).

```
rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, (char*)"default",SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);
snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);
snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params,SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);
snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, 1);
val = 22050;
snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params,&val, &dir);
frames=128;
snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle,params, &frames, &dir);
snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &frames,&dir);
size = frames * 2;

pcmfile=fopen("output.pcm","rb");
fseek(pcmfile,0,SEEK_SET);
buffer=(char*)malloc(size);
memset(buffer,0,size);

if(snd_async_add_pcm_handler(&pcm_callback, handle, MyCallback, NULL) != 0) {
    printf("handler not successful\n");
}

while(!feof(pcmfile)){
    returnvalue=fread(buffer,sizeof(char),size,pcmfile);
    snd_pcm_writei(handle, buffer, frames);
}
```

The above is the piece of code that I am using and the function MyCallback is defined. Could you point to me the possible mistake.

Comment: You can call _const char* snd_strerror(int errnum)_ to get a message from your error code, that may help (http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___error.html#gd174fcc147831046749051725762dd69)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The description was "Function not Implemented". Any how it seems like using asynchronous alsa callbacks in not recommended anyway for porting etc. Is there an other method so that I can implement paus/resume functionality at the application level.

Comment: Since what I needed was pause/play functionality, I ended up breaking the PCM data into small chunks and write one by one to ALSA. If Pause() is called then I would just stop writing those chunks.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem with exactly the same symptoms as yours so I hope the solution is the same.

My solution was that instead of opening the "default" device you open your audio device directly. That is the audio device with a name like "hw:someName".
I believe the original problem is that the "default" device is a virtual device that is interfaced with the pulseAudio Sound server - on my Ubuntu linux it is anyway. Since the pulseAudio sound server does not support the full ALSA API you get the "function not implemented" error.

To clarify the solution, replace

```
rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, (char*)"default",SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
```

with

```
rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, (char*)"hw:someName",SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
```